# StackOverflowError while recursive going throug BufferedImage

Tags: java, recursion, bufferedimage

I have a political map image and I would like to color the countries on it. I load the image into BufferedImage, go through the pixels and color the white ones. I am using recursive method to fill the white spaces and even though it is not infinite(I think so at least) I get StackOverflowError. Also the image that I am using isn't big, it has only 150x160 pixels.

Here is my code. Am I doing something wrong? Is it even good approach ot should I maybe try something else?

```
    private final int[] COLORS = {-65536,-15073025,-16726785,-16711757,-16711919,-256,-417268,-455455,-5741663,-14194369,-14730152,-9885900};

    private int colorCounter;


    private BufferedImage image;

    public ImageColoring(BufferedImage image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public BufferedImage colorImage(){
        for(int i = 0; i<image.getWidth();i++){
            for(int j =0;j<image.getHeight();j++){
                if(image.getRGB(i,j) == -1){
                    fill(i,j);
                    incrementCounter();
                }

            }
        }
        return image;
    }


    private void fill(int x, int y){
        if(x<0 || y<0 || x>=image.getWidth() || y>=image.getHeight()) return;
        if(image.getRGB(x,y)!=-1) return;
        image.setRGB(x,y,COLORS[colorCounter]);
        fill(x+1,y);
        fill(x-1,y);
        fill(x,y+1);
        fill(x,y-1);

    }

    private void incrementCounter(){
        if(++colorCounter == COLORS.length) colorCounter = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: So you are both using a nested for loop *and* recursion to colour your image? I think one of those would be enough...

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution itself sound nice and short, the thing is a image with a y=160, could given your code create a stack of at least size 160 of y-1, not even considering the other cases.

I would suggest to jump to a less stack intensive usage of iteration. 
you could do 4 different loops under each other (not nested!). Makes it less readable, but less space intensive at least.

Comment: I don't know what you intend with four `for` loops, but common flood fill algorithms use a backtracking algorithm with a `Stack` (not the call stack), like the `ArrayDeque`. A common `ArrayList` will also suffice but doesn't have the convenience methods `push()` and `pop()`

Comment: He could replace each recursion call with a iteration loop, `for` was just an example. As the stack structure is not really needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid stack overflow by limiting the recursion to processing a small part of the image. The following code limits the size of the processed area to `SIZE`.
Note that it also reduces the number of time the recursive method is invoked (see comments).

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ImageColoring {

    private static final int COLOR_TO_REPLACE = 0;
    private static final int NEW_COLOR = -15073025;
    private BufferedImage image;
    private static final int SIZE = 10;

    public ImageColoring(BufferedImage image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public BufferedImage colorImage(){

        for(int i = 0; i<image.getWidth();i++){
            for(int j =0;j<image.getHeight();j++){
                if(image.getRGB(i,j) == COLOR_TO_REPLACE){
                    fill(i,j);
                }
            }
        }
        return image;
    }

    private void fill(int x, int y){

        if((x<0) || (y<0) || (x>=image.getWidth()) || (y>=image.getHeight())) {
            return;
        }
        if(image.getRGB(x,y)!= COLOR_TO_REPLACE) {
            return;
        }

        int xMax = ((x + SIZE) > image.getWidth())  ?  image.getWidth() : x + SIZE ;
        int yMax = ((y + SIZE) > image.getHeight()) ?  image.getHeight() : y + SIZE;

        while(fill(x, xMax, y, yMax)) {

            x = xMax; y = yMax;
            xMax = ((x + SIZE) > image.getWidth())  ?  image.getWidth() : x + SIZE ;
            yMax = ((y + SIZE) > image.getHeight()) ?  image.getHeight() : y + SIZE;
        }
    }

    private boolean fill(int x, int xMax, int y, int yMax){

        if( (x>=xMax) || (y>=yMax)) {
            return false;
        }
        if(image.getRGB(x,y)!= COLOR_TO_REPLACE) {
            return false;
        }

        image.setRGB(x,y,NEW_COLOR);

        if(fill(x+1,y, xMax, yMax) ||
                //fill(x-1,y, xMax, yMax)||     not needed. it enough to progress 
                //fill(x,y-1, xMax, yMax) ||    in one direction to cover all 
                fill(x,y+1, xMax, yMax) )   { return true; };

        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String imagePath = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3f/Crystal_Project_bug.png";
        URL url = new URL(imagePath);
        ImageColoring ic = new ImageColoring(ImageIO.read(url));
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel grid = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2, 15, 15));
        grid.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(url))));
        grid.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ic.colorImage())));
        window.add(grid);
        window.pack();
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

(The color changing logic will have to be modified)

[image]